# IE7 bug with show(0).delay(3000).hide(0)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

please give me cross browser solution for script below:

```
 $("#action-notify").show(0).delay(3000).hide(0);
```

it has error in IE7 (problem with 0 in show() method).
without 0 is not work delay after show.

Edit:
script modified. please suggest solution for that script;

Comment: thanx @Nice. it is work setTimeout(function(){ $("#action-notify").hide(); }, 3000); $("#action-notify").show();

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use `delay` for `show` and `hide` ([see here](http://api.jquery.com/delay/#delay1))

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#action-notify").hide();
}, 3000);
$("#action-notify").show(3000);
```

Comment: I am guessing this is because `hide()` doesn't add to animation queue and that's why it doesn't work?

Comment: @Neal, are you sure? `show()` can take a duration and a callback, it looks like an animation method to me. The docs seem to say only the argumentless form is synchronous.

Comment: You can as long as they aren't passed `undefined` -- `$('#action-notify').show(3000).delay(3000).hide(0);`. Without the time, even 0, it won't use the FX queue, which `.delay` depends on to actually delay the next in-queue.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi read here: http://api.jquery.com/delay/ (especially the part about `show` and `hide`)

Comment: @Neal, indeed, `this will not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide()`. The questioner passes a `duration` argument, therefore `show()` behaves like an animation method and `delay()` should work as expected.

Comment: please suggest solution for $("#action-notify").show(0).delay(3000).hide(0);

Comment: @mmtemporary, please update your question with details about the error (the exact error message would be nice).

Comment: setTimeout(function(){
        $("#action-notify").hide();
    }, 3000);
    $("#action-notify").show();